# Ordering when 2 functions are called in a model, one relies on the other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, ruby-on-rails-4

lesson.rb:

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :create_permalink
  before_create :append_order

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }, 
                   uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  .
  .


  def to_param
    permalink
  end

  private

    def create_permalink
      link = self.name.dup
      replacements = [ ["\'", ""], [" ", "-"], ["!", ""] ]
      replacements.each {|replacement| link.gsub!(replacement[0], replacement[1])}
      self.permalink = link.downcase
    end

    def append_order
      self.order = self.order.to_s + '-' + self.permalink
    end
end
```

When I create a new lesson the order is only saving as an integer without appending the permalink on the end. I have made the create_permalink function get called before append_order so it would have something to append but this still doesn't work.

How would I make this work?

Comment: Do you know if the `append_order` method is being called? Does the `order` attribute have the `-` at the end?

Comment: No, it doesn't so it isn't being called, I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you call self.permalink in your append_order method it has not been persisted yet or was not passed as a param into your model, thus it's still nil, to see if it works try calling self.update_attribute(:permalink, value) inside you create_permalink method or move the logic from append_order to create_permalink to avoid an extra db operation